# Is there any way to get how long the chrome browser open using CHROME API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I want to achieve is, if the chrome browser already open in several minutes I want to run `chrome.storage.sync.clear();`

Now I have code when the chrome opens the `chrome.storage.sync.clear();` is run.

Here is my code:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
    chrome.storage.sync.clear();
});
```

but now i want to if the chrome browser is already open in 2 minutes the `chrome.storage.sync.clear();` is run

Comment: Please use this. [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/)

Comment: ...and check what .onStartup really do.   [link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onStartup)